# Using ApplicationUser to get values from another table is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to access `Docente` table using the Application User but the return value of "user.Docente" it's always `null`.

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Docente Docente { get; set; }
}
```

**Docente.cs**

```
public class Docente
{
    public int DocenteId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Imagem { get; set; }
    public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;


        ApplicationUser user = null;
        user = _context.ApplicationUser.Single(u => u.Email.Equals(model.Email));


        var getuserId = user.Docente.DepartamentoId;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your lazy loading is turned off for some reason so I could suggest you to try to include the `Docente` navigation property manually:

```
user = _context.ApplicationUser
               .Include(u => u.Docente) // this requires System.Data.Entity namespace
               .Single(u => u.Email.Equals(model.Email));
```